# redis. how set key name with empty string (not empty value)

Tags: redis

I'm making Redis client with swift.
How can i make key name with empty string. (not empty value)

in redis-cli.
I can make key name with empty string.

```sh
    127.0.0.1:6379> set "" "stringValue"
    OK
```

but, I am using socket to connect Redis server.
and send command, I got error.

```sh
    telnet 127.0.0.1 6379
    Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    
    set "" "stringValue"
    -ERR wrong number of arguments for 'set' command
```

please help me.

Comment: Can you explain why do you need an empty key in redis? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm reading redis document.
(https://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#redis-keys)
the document says 
"Redis keys are binary safe, ... The empty string is also a valid key."

so I am trying to make key with empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the [inline command](https://redis.io/topics/protocol#inline-commands) to send command to Redis, which does not work with binary data, or data which has 0 length or contains whitespace.

Instead, you should use the more [complicated form](https://redis.io/topics/protocol#sending-commands-to-a-redis-server): `*3\r\n$3\r\nset\r\n$0\r\n\r\n$3\r\nval\r\n`

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
*3
$3
set
$0

$3
val
+OK
```